# Sending response from servlet to GWT client

Tags: gwt, servlets

I am building the GWT application where I have to use servlet, I am calling the servlet in the client code using:

```
public class MainEntryPoint extends MenuBar implements EntryPoint {
   int columnLength=0;

   public void onModuleLoad() {
      Window.Location.replace("getData");
   }
}
```

After processing I want to send the result(String array) to client side GWT program from the servlet.
Here I cant use the RPC as the processing can be done only through the Servlet.

Comment: the question is : "how can I send the result to GWT client program from servlet and how I can call the GWT class through servlet".

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in GWT documentation: have you read [Communicating with the server](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get data from servlet and use it in your GWT app?

Note: `Window.Location.replace(url)` will instruct browser to go to the new URL, closing your GWT app (all app state will be lost). This has the same effect as typing new url in browsers url bar.

Use GWT's `RequestBuilder` to get data from  your server. Look at examples at the bottom of the page: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html

Comment: But the problem is, I have to use the HTTPServlet as I the functionality implemented is only obtained through the HttpServlet.

Comment: Again, you have GWT app, but you want to get data from servlet and use it in the GWT app?

Comment: Actually I am reading a data from excel file and when I used Remote Procedure call I was unable to do so now when I called a servlet and read data I was able to read that data, now I have the data in HTTPServlet and want to send this data to GWT client program to display the output using GWT controls, so the data I have in the HTTPServlet has to be passed to the GWT client program.Tell me the way I can call the GWT client class from this servlet.

Comment: You do understand that server can not send data to client when it chooses? HTTP works in request/reply fashion: client requests data (calls your servlet), servlet replies with data. You can not "call GWT client class from the servlet".

Comment: Is there any way to get the response from the servlet in the GWT client, If I cannot get the response from the HttpServlet then what is its usability?

Comment: This is my last comment - it seems that you do not read my answers: client asks for data (= makes a request) and server responds with data (senda back a reply). In GWT you can make a request (and send back a reply) with `RequestBuilder` as described in my answer above.